# Convert non-launchable job to launchable job in Spring Batch Admin

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have a Spring Batch job developed with Spring Boot (1.4.1.RELEASE).

It successfully runs from command line and writes job execution data to MySQL. It shows up as **non-launchable job** in Spring Batch Admin (2.0.0.M1, pointing to MySQL) and I can see job execution metrics.

Now I'd like to turn it into a **launchable** job so I can run it within Spring Batch Admin.

I wonder if anyone has done that before. The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/getting-started.html) has a section **Add your Own Jobs For Launching**. But it does not specify where to add the implementation jar(s) for the job?

Is it **spring-batch-admin/WEB-INF/lib**?

With Spring Boot, the non-launchable job is one big, all-in-one executable jar. Its **dependencies overlap with Spring Batch Admin**. For example, they both have `spring-batch*.jar`, `spring*.jar` but different versions.

Is there a way, like the job definition xml file, to keep them in separate contexts? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch Admin looks for your job definitions in `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/batch/jobs` folder. You could add your `job-definition.xml` file in that folder and define your batch jobs in that xml.

Comment: I understand you can add job-definition.xml in that folder. My question is your job would for sure has your own implementation of reader/writer/processor, which are Java classes and maybe packed in a jar. Where will you put that?

Comment: I quite don't get your question. But from what I understand, you wanted to know the location where your reader/writer/processor Java classes should go ?

Comment: You can place them in any package inside your src folder provided they are registered as `beans` with your application context.